# Ember and d3v4 importing errors

Tags: javascript, d3.js, ember.js

I am trying to use d3v4 in an Emberjs project. I am trying to create a d3js chart inside the Ember components.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-d3

In reactjs - I would import it like this

```
import * as d3 from "d3";
```

but when I try to do that - I get import errors.

```
Could not find module `ember-d3` imported
```

same for just d3

```
Could not find module `d3` imported
```

I have two dependencies in place for d3?

```
   "d3": "^4.2.7",
   "ember-d3": "^0.3.4",
```

Answer (score 1):

After installing browserify

```
npm install --save-dev browserify d3
```

I managed to gain access to d3.js by using this method

```
import d3 from "npm:d3";
```

I am wrapping the chart in a div like this

```
this.$('.wrapper')
```

for the styles for the charts

```
import those in your app/styles/app.scss with @import 'custom-styles.scss';
```

---

so a line chart in ember for me looks like this.

/app/components/line-chart.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import Component from 'ember-component';
import layout from '../templates/components/line-chart';

//import * as d3 from "d3";

import { select } from 'd3-selection';

//import d3 from 'd3';
import d3 from "npm:d3";

const { run, get } = Ember;

export default Component.extend({

    tagName: 'div',

    didReceiveAttrs: function() { 
        // Schedule a call to our `drawCircles` method on Ember's "render" queue, which will
        // happen after the component has been placed in the DOM, and subsequently
        // each time data is changed.
        run.scheduleOnce('render', this, this.drawLineChart);
    },

    drawLineChart(){

        var $this =  this.$('.lineChart');

        var w = $this.data("width");
        var h = $this.data("height");

        var data = [
            {"date": "1-May-12", "close": 45.34},
            {"date": "30-Apr-12", "close": 53.98},
            {"date": "27-Apr-12", "close": 67.00},
            {"date": "23-Apr-12", "close": 166.70}
        ];

        // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
            width = w - margin.left - margin.right,
            height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom;

        // parse the date / time
        var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

        // set the ranges
        var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

        // define the line
        var valueline = d3.line()
            .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
            .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

        // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
        // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
        // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
        var svg = d3.select($this[0]).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
          .append("g")
            .attr("transform",
                  "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

          // format the data
          data.forEach(function(d) {
              d.date = parseTime(d.date);
              d.close = +d.close;
          });

          // Scale the range of the data
          x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
          y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

          // Add the valueline path.
          svg.append("path")
              .data([data])
              .attr("class", "line")
              .attr("d", valueline);

          // Add the X Axis
          svg.append("g")
              .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
              .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

          // Add the Y Axis
          svg.append("g")
              .call(d3.axisLeft(y)); 

    }

});
```

styles/line-chart.scss

```
.lineChart{
    .line {
      fill: none;
      stroke: steelblue;
      stroke-width: 2px;
    }
}
```

and inside app.scss - I import this like so

```
@import "./line-chart.scss";
```

templates/components/line-chart.hbs

```
<div class="lineChart"
    data-width="960"
    data-height="500"
>   
</div>
```

and where you want it to appear.

```
{{line-chart}}
```